# Configure Pi to boot up and run script when plugged in without login

Tags: raspbian, python, boot, operating-systems

> Abandoned post by Unregistered user.

How can i set up my pi zero, so that if I *plug it in*, it runs a python program, without having to login etc?

The project goal is a device that plays an audio file on the push of a hardware button. I would use another hardware button to safely shutdown. My question is: How do I configure the pi so that i can plug it back in, it boots up itself and runs the program without having to use ssh or a keyboard and monitor to login. Can i do that using raspbian or is there maybe a 'lighter' OS that is made for use cases like this one?

thanks in advance!

Comment: You can automatically run a script on boot up, but it will not do a long time because you unplug the RasPi without a graceful shutdown. This will corrupt the operating system after several interruptions.

Comment: I would use a hardware button to safely shutdown.

Comment: Please add this information to your question.

Comment: Abandoned post by Unregistered user.

Answer (score 1):

check this link
https://www.interelectronix.com/raspberry-pi-4-autostart-qt-application-during-boot.html

this was helpful for me I could autostart qt application on a raspberry pi os lite so I think you can run your python program

you just need to create a .service file in the `/etc/systemd/system`

```
cd /etc/systemd/system
sudo nano application_one.service

[Unit]
Description=Qt application autostart
After=graphical.target
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=pi
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/
ExecStart=/home/pi/your_application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

edit this file
then enable this service

```
sudo systemctl enable application_one.service
```

reboot and you will have an autostart of your application

for that you have to remove the login prompt

```
sudo systemctl disable getty@tty1
sudo systemctl mask plymouth-start.service
```

Answer (score 1):

> My question is: How do I configure the pi so that i can plug it back in, it boots up itself and runs the program without having to use ssh or a keyboard and monitor to login.

You don't have to do anything to the RPi to have it start (boot) when power is connected - this is the way it works!

You can use `cron` to start a Python program upon startup - this is very simple. Use the terminal (via SSH if necessary) and Command Line Interface (CLI) as follows:

#### 1. Take care of two (2) **prerequisites**

Once you are logged in as default user `pi`, you are presented with a terminal screen in the `bash` shell. You will see a *prompt* similar to the one shown below indicating where to begin your input.

`pi@raspberrypi4b:~ $`

- You must know the **location** of your program - full path specification; e.g. `/home/pi/MyPythonProgram.py`
- Your program must be marked as **executable**; you can ensure the program is executable with this command:

  ```bsh
  pi@raspberrypi4b:~ $ chmod a+x /home/pi/MyPythonProgram.py
  ```

#### 2. Open your `crontab`for editing:

At the `bash` prompt (`pi@raspberrypi4b:~ $` ), open your `crontab` for editing (choose `nano` as your default editor if asked):

```bsh
$ crontab -e
```

Your default `crontab` will open in the `nano` editor.

#### 3. "Schedule" your program to start each time the RPi boots:

Move the "insertion point" in `nano` just below any existing text in `crontab`, and type the following:

```
@reboot (sleep 20; /home/pi/MyPythonProgram.py) >> /home/pi/logmyprogram.txt 2>&1
```

Here's what this does:

- `@reboot` simply instructs `cron` to execute the following commands each time the system boots.
- `sleep 20` waits 20 seconds after `cron` is started before it starts your program
- your program (assumed to be `/home/pi/MyPythonProgram.py`) is started
- any output or errors (`stdout` or `stderr`, `2>&1`) from your program are ***re-directed*** (`>>`) to a file: `/home/pi/logmyprogram.txt`

`sleep` and the **redirect** are often useful in running `cron` jobs. `sleep` provides additional time for all system resources to get started (e.g. networking services). **redirect (`>>`)** is useful as your *interactive* shell won't be available to receive any output or error messages - instead, they will be written to the logfile you choose.

#### 4. Test

Reboot your system (`sudo reboot` at the shell prompt). Review the logfile for any mesages.

Answer (score 0):

The above example solution worked on my PI Zero after I added the exec python3 to the command string.

@reboot (sleep 20; exec python3 /home/pi/MyPythonProgram.py;) >> /home/pi/logmyprogram.txt 2>&1